Is it possible to use past continuous without a time expression?
From Practical English Usage:

We use the past progressive to say that something was in progress (going on) around a particular past time.

'What were you doing at eight o'clock yesterday evening?' 'I was watching TV.' (NOT What did you do ... ? I watched TV.)
When I got up this morning the sun was shining the birds were singing,... (NOT ... the sun shone, the birds sang ...)


From English Grammar In Use:

I was doing something = I was in the middle of doing it at a certain time.

This time last year I was living in Hong Kong.
What were you doing at 10 o’clock last night?
I waved to Helen, but she wasn’t looking.


Does that mean that past continuous requires a time expression or some kind of past moment/event?
Of course, sometimes it's obvious from the context so it doesn't have to be explicitly stated in the sentence e.g. "I was watching TV." in the first example.
Also leave out situations where past continuous is used in a completely different sense like:

I was hoping we could have dinner together. (from Practical English Usage)


"I was having my breakfast when there was a knock at the door." The approximate time can be guessed from the meal being referred to. Similarly "I was driving home from work when..."  I can't think of a context in which you would use it without any indication of time. "[One day] last week I was gardening when..."

Although a time element might be expressed elsewhere. E.G., "Why are you sweating?" "I was running for the bus."
